# Can't remove duplicates from my randomised list in Python

Tags: python

I'm creating a battleships game in Python, but I want to randomly generate a list of numbers as their location. However, I cannot remove the duplicates, I can use set() but it won't give me 5 results which I need.

```
#Battleships challenge
import random

place = []#empty list
for i in range(5):
               place.append(random.randrange(1,50,1))

print(place)
ships =len(place)


hits = 0
misses = 0
counter = 0
while ships > 0:
               hit = int(input("Which space do you want to hit?"))
               if hit in place:
                              place.remove(hit) 
                              print("You have a hit!")
                              ships = ships -1
                              hits = hits + 1
               else:
                              print("No!")
                              misses = misses + 1

if ships == 0:
               print("Well done, all ships have disappeared!")
               print(hits, "successful hits")
               print(misses,"misses")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_positions = range(100)
five_positions = random.sample(all_positions,5)
```

I think would work

Comment: Thanks! I did try random.sample but not that way, it works now!